# Working and calculating with geographic positions

Tags: c++, geospatial

I was thinking about how to implement a GPS navigation for my quadcopter.  I was writing some functions to calculate the angle between two positions (from home point to the target).

I'd like a review of this code.  I am not very sure whether I was calculating the geographic position right.

```
/*
 * Geographic calculations
 */
float UAVNav::width_of_merid_m(const float fLat_deg) {  
  float fdX_m = _2PI * _RADIUS_EARTH_m * cos(ToRad(fLat_deg) );
  fdX_m /= 360.f;
  return fdX_m;
}

float UAVNav::dist_2_equat_m(const float fLat_deg) {
  return (_PERIMETER_EARTH_m / 360.f) * fLat_deg;
}

float UAVNav::dist_2_greenw_m(const float fLat_deg, const float fLon_deg) {    
  return width_of_merid_m(fLat_deg) * fLon_deg;
}

float UAVNav::home_2_target_deg() { 
  const float fMod = 10000000.f;
  GPSPosition target = m_pReceiver->m_Waypoint;
  GPSData home = m_pHalBoard->get_gps();

  float fLatHome_deg = home.latitude / fMod;
  float fLonHome_deg = home.longitude / fMod;

  float fLatTarg_deg = target.latitude / fMod;
  float fLonTarg_deg = target.longitude / fMod;

  float fXHome = dist_2_greenw_m(fLatHome_deg, fLonHome_deg);
  float fYHome = dist_2_equat_m(fLatHome_deg);

  float fXTarg = dist_2_greenw_m(fLatTarg_deg, fLonTarg_deg);
  float fYTarg = dist_2_equat_m(fLatTarg_deg);

  float dX = fXTarg - fXHome;
  float dY = fYTarg - fYHome;

  // Calculate the angle to the destination direction
  // NOTE: Here the system is inverted by 90° to align the magnetic north to 0°
  m_fDestin_deg = ToDeg(atan2((float)dX, (float)dY) );
  return m_fDestin_deg;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some temporary variables that you might not use, such as `fLatTarg_deg` and `fLotTarg_deg`: you can commit the operation along with the function call.

Also, the variables (which are actually costants, probably) `_RADIUS_EARTH_m` and `_PERIMETER_EARTH_m` are breaking the [standard C++ naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#C_and_C.2B.2B).

Comment: @syb0rg Hope you won't mind, but did you seriously edit my answer to add a new line?

Comment: It seems like he did. Isn't it better that way ?

Comment: @no1 I was out of votes for the day, and I had used one of my last votes on your answer.  Then I bought the unicorn animation, and I may have wanted to test it out. ;)

Comment: @syb0rg shame on you, if you spend 40 votes, why not buy the unicorn animation ***before*** doing so ??

Answer (score 2):

You naming convention is a bit weird. My assumption is that `fLat` stands for "float latitude". Because it is quite easy to know the type of a variable, there's no need for having the `f` prefix.

You don't need to cast to `float` in `m_fDestin_deg = ToDeg(atan2((float)dX, (float)dY) );`.

You don't need the temporary variable in `UAVNav::width_of_merid_m` especially as it makes the mathematical formula harder to read.

Your method `UAVNav::home_2_target_deg()` seems to be doing two things : returning a value and updating a member. It would be clearer to have a (const) method returning a value and another method using it to set a member.

Answer (score 2):

- You don't have `std::` in front of `cos()` and `atan2()` (which belong to `<cmath>`), which means you're using `using namespace std`.  This is discouraged as it could cause bugs in cases of name-clashing with existing names used in this namespace (or any `namespace`, although `std` is most commonly used).  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more information.
- I agree with @Josay about the casting being unnecessary in `atan2()`.  Its two arguments are already `float`, so casting will do nothing.

  Moreover, when you *do* need casts like these, prefer `static_cast<>()` in C++:

  ```
  static_cast<type>(object);
  ```

  More info about different types of casts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255015/1950231).

Comment: I use math.h for reason and don't use: "using namespace whatever" in the whole program.

Comment: @dgrat: Okay.  Without showing the `#include`s, I would not have been able to tell.

Comment: Well, I switched to static casts. The main reason why I was not using them is, that they look ugly, make code longer and contain even more brackets.

Comment: @dgrat: I do agree that they're quite a bit longer.  It may not matter much for smaller programs, though.